# Check if String is within the range or not

Tags: java

I have a variable of type String loanTerm and want to check whether it is within the range 1-999. It can contain NA or number from 1-999 (exclude decimal) and can't be blank. I have used @NotNull, @Range(min=1,max=999) but couldn't able to perform complete validation.

Comment: What are those annotations? Why did you expect those to work?

Comment: you can do that by simply if...else... conditions

Comment: @Apurba You need to explain your question a little better. I am sure your will find your answer if you do that.

Comment: I have an attribute of type String (LoanTerm) in my pojo class and need to validate the attribute. Following are the validations I need to do on LoanTerm : 1)  It should not be blank. 2) It should contain values from 1-999. 3) It should not contain decimals. 4) It can contain 'NA' I have used  @NotBlank annotation to check that field shouldn't be blank. @Range(min=1,max=999) to check field should have values from 1-999. But I am not getting how to check for decimal and NA part.

Comment: look in to this,you can try to use @Digit with some condition  http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html_single/#table-spec-constraints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in pojo class use the following set method for loanTerm.

```
setloanTerm(String str){
  if(str != null && str !=""&&Integer.parseInt(str) >=0 && Integer.parseInt(str)<=999){
  loanTerm=str;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see if string within a range the simplest way is to use if statement with String.compareTo() method:

```
if(str.compareTo(lower) > 0 && upper.compareTo(str) < 0){
       System.out.println("inside the range");
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, check it whether it is empty or not. Than you can use Integer class to check whether it can be cast to Integer or not.

```
Integer validateLoanTerm(String loanTerm) {
    if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(loanTerm) && Integer.parseInt(loanTerm) > 0 && Integer.parseInt(loanTerm) < 999) {
       return Integer.parseInt(loanTerm);
    }

    return null;
}
```

I used Integer value as return value of the method. However if you do not need the value of it, you can just return a boolean from the method.